# How does one do a Wald test on estimates from two variables?

Tags: variance, stata, covariance, covariance-matrix

> Given a dataset with two variables $X$ and $Y$, with each observation independent of the others, test the null hypothesis $$\mu_X = \mu_Y\\ \sigma^2_X = \sigma^2_Y$$ using a Wald test.

This question comes from a textbook, but my answer isn't going to be handed in. Hence, I'm posting this question here because I'd like my work to be checked. Our class was given a dataset to use for this question, and I use Stata. I'm not sure of the best way to solve this question—the main struggle I had was with figuring out how to find the variance-covariance matrix for the Wald statistic, as I didn't think it was possible to create a MLE random variable for $\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}$ and $\widehat{\sigma_X^2} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}$, in order to find their variances and covariances.

To implement the Wald test, I construct the vector of restrictions such that it is predicted to equal $\boldsymbol 0$. In this case, that is $$\left[\begin{matrix}
{{\mu_X - \mu_Y}} \\
\sigma^2_X - \sigma^2_Y
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
For notational convenience, label this $\boldsymbol v$. Then $\boldsymbol{{\hat v'}}\left(\Sigma_{\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}}\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}$ is the Wald Statistic. The covariance matrix is
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_{\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}} &= (\boldsymbol{{\hat v}} - \mathrm E[\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}])(\boldsymbol{{\hat v}} - \mathrm E[\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}])' \\
 &=\left[\begin{matrix}
 \mathrm{Var}(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}) & \mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right) \\
 \mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right) & \mathrm{Var}\left(\widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)
 \end{matrix}\right] \end{align*}

Let's look at each element of the matrix in turn:
\begin{align*}
&&\mathrm{Var}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}\right) &= \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right) \\
&& &= \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac 1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - y_i)\right)\right) \\
&& &=\frac1{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var}(x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}(y_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n 2\mathrm{Cov}(x_i, y_i)\right) \\
&& &= \frac1n\left(\sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y - 2\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)\right)
\end{align*}
where the observations (individuals) are independent of each other, so $\mathrm{Cov}(x_i, y_j) = 0 $ for $i\neq j$. This scalar will be computed in Stata. Easy enough, but trying to use this same method of deriving formulae for the other entries in terms of $\mu_X, \mu_Y, \sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ [seems to be difficult](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-jtgnwQX4lnjb5l_e_d7m0C115EgG-Y/view?usp=sharing). (In order to do that, I would use the expected value formula for a variance $\mathrm{Var}(W) = \mathrm E[W^2] - \mathrm E[W]^2$, and substitute $x_i = \mu_X + \varepsilon_{X,i}$ (also with $y_i$) to use that fact that $\mathrm E[\varepsilon_{X,i}^2] = \sigma_X^2$ (also with $\varepsilon_{Y, i}^2$).)

I chose a simpler method of generating variables for $(X-\mu_X)^2$ and $(Y-\mu_Y)^2$ in Stata, in order to compute the covariances according to the formulae written below.

The second and third entries are
$$%
\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right) 
= \mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X}\right) - \mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X}\right) -\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X}, \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right) + \mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)%
$$
Where
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X}\right) 
 &= \mathrm{Cov}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2\right) \\
 &= \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathrm{Cov}\left(x_i, (x_j - \mu_X)^2\right)\\
 &\text{where $x_i$ and $(x_j - \mu)^2$ are not correlated when $i\neq j$} \\
 &= \frac 1n\mathrm{Cov}\left(X, (X - \mu_X)^2\right)
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{multline*}
\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right) \\
 =\frac 1n\bigg(\mathrm{Cov}\left(X, (X - \mu_X)^2\right) - \mathrm{Cov}\left(Y, (X-\mu_X)^2\right) - \mathrm{Cov}\left(X, (Y-\mu_Y)^2\right) + \mathrm{Cov}\left(Y, (Y - \mu_Y)^2\right)\bigg)
\end{multline*}

Lastly, $\mathrm{Var}\left(\widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)$
\begin{align*}
 &= \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac 1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \mu_X)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \mu_Y)^2\right)\right) \\
 &= \frac 1{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}\left((x_i - \mu_X)^2\right) + \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}\left((y_i - \mu_Y)^2\right) - \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Cov}\Big((x_i - \mu_X)^2, (y_i - \mu_Y)^2\Big)\right) \\
 &= \frac 1n\bigg(\mathrm{Var}\left((X - \mu_X)^2\right) + \mathrm{Var}\left((Y - \mu_Y)^2\right) - \mathrm{Cov}\Big((X - \mu_X)^2, (Y - \mu_Y)^2\Big)\bigg)
\end{align*}

For each of these formulae for the entries of the matrix, substituting $\mu_X = \widehat{\mu_X},\ \mu_Y = \widehat{\mu_Y},\ \sigma_X^2 = \widehat{\sigma^2_X},$ and $\sigma_Y^2 = \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}$ is asymptotically valid. Hence, [my Stata code is this](https://pastebin.com/hE5kFXeG).

I thought of using the Fisher Information matrix $I(\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}) \approx \Sigma_{\boldsymbol{{\hat v}}}^{-1}$ according to the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound, but I don't know how to differentiate the bivariate loglikelihood w.r.t. an *expression* (i.e. $\mu_X - \mu_Y$). I have found the bivariate loglikelihood function under the assumption of normality.

Comment: Formulae for the moments of the sample moments are set out in [O'Neill (2014)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2014.966589).  These are for a single IID sample, so you will need to extend to look at bivariate data, but this should get you started.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag, and read its tag wiki

Comment: With regards to the [tag:self-study] tag, I am not handing this work in (there are no handed-in tutorials in my Masters course). It is only part of my own study routine, as I am going through the questions in the textbook linked at the top of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The OP seeks:

1. $\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)$
2. $\mathrm{Var}\left(\widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)$

## Notation

These are *moments of moments* problems, in particular finding *population* moments of *sample* moments, in a bivariate world. Such problems are not generally easy to solve by hand, and the *modus operandi* for solving them is to work with power sum notation, which in our bivariate world is of form $s_{r,t}$, namely:

$$s_{r,t}=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r Y_i^t$$

In this power sum notation, the sample mean estimators are:

- $\widehat{\mu_X} =  \frac{s_{1,0}}{n}  \quad \quad \quad \widehat{\mu_Y} =  \frac{s_{0,1}}{n}$

... and the MLE sample variance estimators are:

- $\widehat{\sigma^2_X}: \quad   m_{2,0} = \frac{s_{2,0}}{n}-\frac{s_{1,0}^2}{n^2}   \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}: \quad  m_{0,2} = \frac{s_{0,2}}{n}-\frac{s_{0,1}^2}{n^2}$

### Answer 1

Find: $\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X} - \widehat{\mu_Y}, \widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)$

Since the covariance operator denotes the $\mu_{1,1}$ Central Moment, we can find the covariance using the *mathStatica* (for *Mathematica*) package function:

[image]

where the solution is expressed in terms of central moments of the population, namely:

- $\mu _{r,s}$ denotes the product central moment:

$$\mu _{r,s}=E\left[(X-E[X]]^r (Y-E[Y])^s\right]$$

For example, $\mu_{1,1} = \text{Cov}(X,Y)$, $\mu_{2,0}= \text{Var}(X)$ and $\mu_{0,2}= \text{Var}(Y)$.

### Answer 2

Find: $\mathrm{Var}\left(\widehat{\sigma^2_X} - \widehat{\sigma^2_Y}\right)$

Since the variance operator denotes the $2^{\text{nd}}$ Central Moment, we can find the desired variance using the *mathStatica* package function:

[image]

**More detail**

There is an extensive discussion of 'moment of moment' problems in Chapter 7 of our book:

- Rose and Smith,  "*Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*", Springer, NY

A free download of the written chapter is available here:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

which also includes references for further reading. You may also find of interest Chapter 13 of:

- Stuart and Ord (1994), *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*

... but it is very hard to solve such problems by hand.

As disclosure, I should note that I am an author of the `CentralMomentToCentral` function used above.

Comment: Thank you! This does indeed answer my question of what the formulae for $\mathrm{Cov}\left(\widehat{\mu_X}-\widehat{\mu_Y},\widehat{\sigma_X^2} - \widehat{\sigma_Y^2}\right)$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left(\mathrm{\sigma_X^2} - \widehat{\sigma_Y^2}\right)$ are in terms of the moments. Take my upvote.   Are there any mistakes in my own calculations in the question?